# Error: Object has no mesh data to be used for ray casting

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I'm writing an operator that casts rays from the center towards certain amounts of points and finds the faces rays hit. I'm facing this annoying error, when I change the property of the operator.

I've managed to strip the code down to minimal code to reproduce this, that works on default scene

Code:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.props import *
from mathutils import *

class SomeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "some_operator"
    bl_label = "Some operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

    prop = IntProperty(name="Prop",
        description="Prop",
        min=10,
        max=50,
        default=10)

    def execute(self, context):

        obj = context.active_object

        if bpy.context.mode != 'OBJECT':
            raise Exception("Please switch to object mode")

        cover = [Vector((0,0,1)), Vector((0,0,-1)), Vector((1,0,0)), Vector((-1,0,0))]

        for pt in cover:
            dummy1, dummy2, faceInd = obj.ray_cast(Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), pt)

            obj.data.polygons[faceInd].select = True

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

When you change the SomeProp value, the error occurs.

Comment: I'm getting this too when I do mesh.ray_cast, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need `bpy.context.scene.update()` just after `execute()` for it to work. It seems it needs to update some internal relationships.

Full code (modified to work on 2.78):

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.props import *
from mathutils import *

class SomeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Some operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

    prop = IntProperty(name="Prop",
        description="Prop",
        min=10,
        max=50,
        default=10)

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.scene.update()
        obj = context.active_object

        if bpy.context.mode != 'OBJECT':
            raise Exception("Please switch to object mode")

        cover = [Vector((0,0,1)), Vector((0,0,-1)), Vector((1,0,0)), Vector((-1,0,0))]

        for pt in cover:
            dummy0, dummy1, dummy2, faceInd = obj.ray_cast(Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), pt)

            obj.data.polygons[faceInd].select = True

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SomeOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SomeOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

# test call
#bpy.ops.object.some_operator()
```

Answer (score -1):

This error happens if you try to raycast in edit mode. For whatever reason, you can only raycast in object mode.

Comment: I get this error in object mode (and edit mode).